# Can someone help me with this css issue?

Tags: css

Can someone help me with this CSS issue i am having? I would like to create an HTML call out box with the arrow pointing inside the div. all the tutorials I have seen so far have the arrow pointing to the left, right, top or bottom.
I am using the example from here http://cssarrowplease.com/

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 1):

Rotate it and also change the top, left and margin's position accordingly

```
 .arrow_box:after, .arrow_box:before {
    left: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
   -ms-transform: rotate(180deg); /* IE 9 */
   -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
   transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.arrow_box {
 position: relative;
 background: #88b7d5;
 border: 4px solid #c2e1f5;
    margin-top:150px;
    margin-left:150px;
    padding:15px;
    height:150px;
    width:60%;
    text-align:center;
    line-height: 100px;
}
.arrow_box:after, .arrow_box:before {
     bottom: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    border: solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    content: " ";
    top: -4px;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.arrow_box:after {
 border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);   
    border-bottom-color: #FFF;
    border-width: 30px;
    margin-left: -30px;
}
.arrow_box:before {
     border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #c2e1f5;
    border-width: 36px;
    margin-left: -36px;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow_box">
            <h1 class="logo">css arrow please!</h1>
          </div>
```

and here is the demo working code for this code

**[Demo code](https://jsfiddle.net/7tfs9v4s/)**

Comment: @Awakened look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change the position of the :before and :after pseudo-elements:

http://jsfiddle.net/7nmtgoqo/2/

typically arrow right in this generator has a style rule `left:100%;` and :after has a border-color that matches the div background.  if you update the values for `left` and `top` it will move the arrow around while keeping it's shape...in the fiddle I've commented the css lines I updated from the cssarrowplease generated styles.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can get your requirements done by this simple code:

```
<style>
.outerDiv{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:red
}

.inwardArrow{
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;

    border-top: 20px solid white;
}
</style>

<div class="outerDiv">
<div class="inwardArrow"></div>
</div>
```